# In a JFET, is the gate *always* connected to the bulk/substrate?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, semiconductors, jfet

In a JFET, is the gate *always* connected to the bulk/substrate ?
Or is there "no rule" (sometimes it is, sometimes it is not)?

And what about the case of the MOSFET ?

[image]

Comment: Mosfet gates are floating

Comment: @tobalt : apologizes : what does it mean "floating" : are there *connected* or *not connected* ?

Comment: Do you mean Source connected to Substrate? Because Gate connected to Substrate makes no sense. You could not control the transistor.

Comment: @Justme ; I really mean "is Gate connected to substrate" (no typo)

Comment: I added a schematic (from me) : where the Gate (the P+ of the gate) is connected to the substrate P+

Comment: floating means fully DC-isolated.

Comment: @tobalt : I added a schematic

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian The colours shown in your image represent the material type. Just because the gate is the same colour as the substrate does not mean they are connected. For the same reason, because the source & gate are the same colours doesn't mean they are connected. When I look at the image you posted, I don't see the gate connected to the substrate, I see them as isolated entities.

Comment: From Elliott and nanofarad's comments: I think you need to clarify on the question, what do you actually mean by 'connected'.

Comment: by "connected" : I just mean : there is no electric resistance, or negligeable electric resistance. Remark : please note that the figure is not an official one : this is my that drawed it by hand, so there is no warranty that my schematic is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a JFET is produced using the common planar process, the channel is first diffused into the bulk and, in order to insulate this region from it, the bulk is given the same doping as the gate region. Thus, a junction of the same kind as the gate-channel junction (except perhaps for the doping concentration values) is already present on the device; thus a JFET is already present. The subsequent diffusion of the gate region into the channel region creates the final, more performant device: it is like having two JFETs with the channel regions connected in parallel. At this point you have to chose if it is worth keeping the two devices separated or not. It turns out that, while it is possible to keep the two devices separated, it is better both from the point of view of performance and feasibility to make them work as one single device. **In short the gate and bulk regions are hardwired together in every JFET**.

**Notes**

- The situation is quite different for small signal (depletion) MOSFETs: for these devices, keeping the bulk and the gate terminals separated is like having a device made of a MOSFET and a JFET with parallel channels, which may be useful in some circumstances. The standard NXP-Philips [BSV81 depletion MOSFET](https://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf/download.php?id=4abb491bdea097de51692ca1de8226b10c5788&type=M&term=BSV81) is an example of this kind of device.
- Note also that the above statement is strictly true only for *discrete* JFET devices. Analog Devices, in some of its high performance OpAmps, uses [a patented circuit](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4639683A) whose input JFETs have their bulk terminal *not connected* to their gate: it instead goes to a bias network, and this allows an order of magnitude reduction in their gate bias current and better temperature behavior of this parameter (it increases less with the junction temperature compared to standard JFETs).
- **New edit**. Recently I "discovered" the (unfortunately not freely available) following paper by R.S.C. Cobbold and F.N. Trofimenkoff "[Four-terminal field-effect transistors](https://doi.org/10.1109/T-ED.1965.15488)", IEEE Transactions on Electron Devices, Vol. 12, Issue 5, pp. 246 - 247 (1965). The authors describe how the different doping of the gate and bulk regions and of the channel the behind them give each electrode a distinctive (nevertheless similar) behavior.

Comment: Thank you, do you agree that your answer *contradicts* what other people say (at least, this contradict "Justme" who stated, without telling if he means jfet or mosfet, that there are not connected). ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian I agree, but I cannot deny what I know from my engineering training. Also, if you look at the JFET image you’ve added to your question, you see immediately the two parallel structures: the bulk (substrate) region has the same depletion effect on the channel that the gate region has. Their hardwiring, when there’s no need of building a thin gate oxide region, is the most natural and useful choice.

Comment: ok thank you. Please note tha tthe schematic is from me : I drawn it by myself as a synthesis of looking at various sources on the web and in books, because none of the schematics that I found were pedagogic enough from my point of view. Your explanation is the best one and you are the only one who understood my question. I give you the accepted answer. Thanks for having shared your knowledge.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian oh, however it is a nice picture. It describes in a simple le but correct way what it really happens.

Comment: As a bonus, would you confirm what other people stated for the case of *MOSFET* : in MOSFET, there is no electric connection between gate and substrate ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian yes, this is true. In ordinary MOSFETs the bulk terminal is connected to the source one of the device at the case level only to avoid the “kink” effect on the \$I_\text{DS}=f(V_\text{DS})\$ characteristic. In small signal enhancement devices, the bulk (B) terminal is mostly made available to the user.

Answer (score 4):

A MOSFET is a 4-terminal device: gate, drain, source, and body. If you buy a discrete MOSFET it is likely that the manufacturer has connected the source to the body, but this is not required.

In your diagram the gate **is not** connected to the body. There is a thin insulating layer between the gate itself (colored gray) and the body underneath (colored blue).

Comment: ok, I agree with your explanation, for the case of the MOSFET, because there is an insulating layer. But what about the case of the *JFET* ? (there is no insulating layer for JFET)

Comment: I don't think you have shown us what kind of JFET construction you are talking about. If the gate and substrate have an **ohmic** connection then you don't really have a substrate at all, just a giant gate. If they are touching but **junction isolated** then I would not say that they are **connected** at all.

Comment: I'm not aware that there are several possible JFET constructions.

Answer (score 4):

There is no hard rule. There are many structures. Connecting the JFET gate to substrate increases the transconductance at the cost of increased gate capacitance. Connecting the substrate to the source reverses this.

On monolithic IC, the substrate is common to all devices. For the common P-type, it's normally connected to the most negative power supply. But for P-channel devices on a P-substrate, you need an "N-well" that serves as a local substrate. For CMOS digital circuits, you usually connect all the N-wells to the most positive supply, but for mixed-signal circuits it's sometimes useful to modulate the gate threshold by adjusting the N-well bias for individual transistors.

And then there are vertical MOSFETS, SOI devices, N substrates, many variations and many ways to connect them...

Answer (score 1):

No, gate is never connected to substrate.

You need gate and substrate to be isolated to be able to control the gate voltage to turn the transistor on and off.

Comment: but in the case of *JFET*, since there is no insulating layer, isn't it that the gate is connected to the substrate ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian How do you actually define *connected*? Is being separated by a depletion region at a reverse-biased PN junction considered "connected" under your definition or not?

Comment: by "connected", I mean no electric resistance, or negligeable electric resistance. So a reverse-biased PN junction is "not connected".

Comment: The JFET gate is comparable to a MOSFET gate, even if JFET gate has no insulation. So also JFET gate has extremely high impedance, which is negligible. JFET gate is a reverse biased PN junction, so it does not conduct. Not very well at least. The leakage current is in picoamps range, maybe nanoamps range max.